# XSLT template match and output multiple nodes in one html element

Tags: xml, xslt

I hope someone can help me joining XML nodes to one html output element!

I have XML like this:

```
<book>
  <section type="chapter">
    <p type="chapterNumber">Chapter 1</p>
    <p type="chapterTitle">This is the very first chapter of this book</p>
    <p type="normaltext">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </section>

  <section type="chapter">
    <p type="chapterNumber">Chapter 2</p>
    <p type="chapterTitle">This is the second chapter of this book</p>
    <p type="normaltext">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </section>

  <section type="chapter">
    <p type="chapterNumber">Chapter 3</p>
    <p type="chapterTitle">This is the third chapter of this book</p>
    <p type="normaltext">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </section>
 </book>
```

I want to transform the xml to this html (joining p type="chapterNumber" and p type="chapterTitle" into one single h1 tag for each section in the book) :

```
 <html>
 <head><title>My book</title></head>
  <body>
    <section class="chapter">
    <h1>Chapter 1 - This is the very first chapter of this book</h1>
    <p class="normaltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </section>

    <section class="chapter">
    <h1>Chapter 2 - This is the second chapter of this book</h1>
    <p class="normaltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </section>

   <section class="chapter">
   <h1>Chapter 2 - This is the third chapter of this book</h1>
   <p class="normaltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </section>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the xslt I have for now, where chapterNumer is transformed into one h1 and chapterTitle is transformed into another h1 element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head><title>My book</title></head>
    <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="book/section[@type="chapter"]">
    <section>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>

<xsl:template match="book/section[@type="chapter"]/p[@type="chapterNumber"]">
    <h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="book/section[@type="chapter"]/p[@type="chapterTitle"]">
    <h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="book/section[@type="chapter"]/p[@type="normal"]">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is the input regular so that there always is `p type="chapterNumber"` as the first child element of a `section type="chapter` and `p type="chapterTitle"` as the second child element?

Answer (score 0):

If you process the following sibling of the `p type="chapterNumber"` directly you can adapt your code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head><title>My book</title></head>
    <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="book/section[@type='chapter']">
    <section class="chapter">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book/section[@type='chapter']/p[@type='chapterNumber']">
    <h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[@type = 'chapterTitle']/node()"/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book/section[@type='chapter']/p[@type='chapterTitle']"/>

<xsl:template match="book/section[@type='chapter']/p[@type='normaltext']">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```